# SSIS ForEach Loop Not Iterating Over All Items in a Folder

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, etl, foreach-loop-container

I have 4 excel files in a single folder. 2 have single sheets with the same name and the other 2 have 2 sheets each (the sheet i want data from have same names).

- I used a ForEach loop in SSIS to iterate over all the files in the folder.
- I assigned the initial path to a variable i.e. ExcelFilePath.
- I configured this variable in my loop container so it can hold the path to all the files in the folder.
- I've passed this variable as an expresson in Excel File Path property in my Excel Connection Manager string.

This is the design of my project:

[image: Design of my project]

However, when I execute the package, only the first data flow object i.e. for Branches gets executed successfully. I figure this is because its path is hardcoded in my variable. All other data flow objects fail.

Execution Result:

[image: Execution Result]

Logs:

```
Error: 0xC004701C at COUNTRY_INFO, SSIS.Pipeline: OLE DB
Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input].Columns[COUNTRY_CODE] has
lineage ID 255 that was not previously used in the Data Flow task.
Error: 0xC004706B at MG_SEND, SSIS.Pipeline: "Excel Source" failed
validation and returned validation status "VS_ISBROKEN". 
Error: 0xC004700C at MG_SEND, SSIS.Pipeline: One or more component failed
validation. Error: 0xC0024107 at MG_SEND: There were errors during
task validation.
Error: 0xC004706B at COUNTRY_INFO, SSIS.Pipeline: "OLE DB Destination"
failed validation and returned validation status "VS_NEEDSNEWMETADATA".
```

I've set DelayValidation to True for each component.
RetainSameConnection is False in the Connection string Properties.

EDIT:
Tried adding a sequence container with Precedence Constraint arrows so the path is only redirect to the respective DFT. Delay Validation is set to True for all components.

Design:

[image: Current Package Design]

Execution Result is as follows:
[image: Execution Result After Changes]

Log:

```
    Error: 0xC001000E at Package1: The connection "" is not found. This error is thrown by Connections collection when the specific connection element is not found.
Error: 0xC02020EA at Package1, Log provider "SSIS log provider for SQL Server": The connection manager "" is not found. A component failed to find the connection manager in the Connections collection.
Error: 0xC001000E at Package1: The connection "" is not found. This error is thrown by Connections collection when the specific connection element is not found.
Error: 0xC02020EA at Package1, Log provider "SSIS log provider for SQL Server": The connection manager "" is not found. A component failed to find the connection manager in the Connections collection.
Warning: 0x80019002 at Package1: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (2) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.
Information: 0x4004300A at BRANCHES, SSIS.Pipeline: Validation phase is beginning.
Warning: 0x800470C8 at BRANCHES, Excel Source [26]: The external columns for Excel Source are out of synchronization with the data source columns. The column "BRANCH_CODE" needs to be added to the external columns.
The column "BRANCH_NAME" needs to be added to the external columns.
The column "AGENT_ID" needs to be added to the external columns.
The column "MAKER" needs to be added to the external columns.
The column "CHECKER" needs to be added to the external columns.
The column "CREATE_DATE" needs to be added to the external columns.
The column "BRANCH_COUNTRY" needs to be added to the external columns.
The column "CREATE_STATUS" needs to be added to the external columns.
The Excel Source.Outputs[Excel Source Output].ExternalColumns[IS_RECEIVE_ACTIVE] needs to be removed from the external columns.
The Excel Source.Outputs[Excel Source Output].ExternalColumns[IS_SEND_ACTIVE] needs to be removed from the external columns.
The Excel Source.Outputs[Excel Source Output].ExternalColumns[BASE_RECEIVE_CURRENCY] needs to be removed from the external columns.
The Excel Source.Outputs[Excel Source Output].ExternalColumns[COUNTRY_NAME] needs to be removed from the external columns.
The Excel Source.Outputs[Excel Source Output].ExternalColumns[COUNTRY_LEGACY_CODE] needs to be removed from the external columns.
The Excel Source.Outputs[Excel Source Output].ExternalColumns[COUNTRY_CODE] needs to be removed from the external columns.
Error: 0xC004706B at BRANCHES, SSIS.Pipeline: "Excel Source" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_NEEDSNEWMETADATA".
Error: 0xC004700C at BRANCHES, SSIS.Pipeline: One or more component failed validation.
Error: 0xC0024107 at BRANCHES: There were errors during task validation.
```

Please note that ExcelFilePath variable set for BRANCHES path initially. Also, I've tested the container through a Script Task and it is indeed looping over all the paths in the folder.

Comment: It sounds like the files are not in the same format/have the same headers.

Comment: All the files + OLEDB destinations are different. Basically, I'm dealing with 4 different schemas. Will the ForEach loop not work in this case?

Comment: You created 4 different Data Flow Task for your 4 Excel Files? If that's so, what is the use of 'For each loop' container?

Comment: Correct you can not have a for each loop assuming the schema is the same.  If you have 4 different files just create 4 different data flow tasks.  If you need to loop through the files (maybe some have the same format) you can do the for/each loop but need a check at the top for what data flow task to run for each file based off the name then run this flow, but sounds like all you need are 4 different data flow tasks and no loop needed.

Comment: @Brad, No I didn't mean that. 4 DFT will be inefficient and bad design.   One DFT in for each loop container is enough. You put the filePath in a variable, and made the connection string dynamic. Then went on to configure For each file enumerator, and selected all excel files with the extension (*.xlsx), then assigned the filePath variablename FilePath to '0' index. All seems OK. I can't understand why It fails.

Comment: The purpose of using the ForEach container is is so that i can loop over all the files in the folder. I can't make 4 different excel connections pointing to the 4 excel files respectively. That would be a very inefficient design. I have to make the excel connection dynamic so that it will pick each excel file and migrate the data to the respective table.

Answer (score 0):

A data flow works based on the design-time premise that the source data which exactly conforms to the design-time value will be loaded super fast and shoved into this destination which also match the design-time value.

SSIS cannot be a generic source to destination engine. It's not how the product is designed.

A step that happens in every package execution every time is Validation. The goal of the validation step is to fail early if something does not meet the contract upon which data flows were built.

You can change the validation to occur on package start to on *task* start. That way, if you are pulling data from a source that is created in a precursor step, the package will run validation only when the task begins.

What is happening here is that the one Excel connection manager you have is valid for the first Data Flow Task but invalid for the remainder. To get around this, you need to instruct SSIS to wait to validate.

With all of that said, to make your design work as intended:

- Update the Excel Connection Manager Property of DelayValidation to True
- Update the 4 Data Flow Tasks to have a property of DelayValidation to True

Now, those 5 changes are not enough to make your process work. Because when the Branches file is found, the COUNTRY_INFO data flow is still going to fire and the metadata does not match.

To rectify this, you need to have a precursor task that does nothing but simply serves as an anchor point. I find Sequence Container to work nicely here

[image]

Notice that the green connector has a little f(x) between the sequence container and the data flow tasks. That's because I have changed the Evaluation operation to  "Expression and Constraint".

The constraint is the final piece of the puzzle. You need to make this condition true when the name matches whatever the data flow is.

Let's assume that the words in your data flow exist in the file name which is surfaced in the Foreach Enumerator into variable @[User::ExcelFilePath]

The expression for BRANCHES would be something like

```
FINDSTRING(UPPER(@[User::ExcelFilePath]), "BRANCHES" , 1 ) > 0
```

That is: Cast the value of Excel File Path to all upper case. If the also-all-uppercase word BRANCHES is in the file path, the FindString method will return a number starting at 1 or greater. If the number from FindString is non-zero, then TRUE, otherwise, it's false

Repeat this pattern for each branch.

What happens is that the path will only light up when the expected file is enumerated (and then validate). Wrong file paths won't light up and therefore won't fail validation.

### Edit to address the updated question

The Design data flow shows you have broken components I would not expect execution to succeed.

Comment: Hi, I've already tried this. Editing my post with the current structure I have. I still get mapping errors despite setting DelayValidation to True. I've tested my loop through a Script Task and it is returning all the 4 paths in the folder. However, upon package execution, if initial path is set to BRANCHES path, BRANCHES DFT will work and COUNTRY_INFO DFT configuration will have mapping errors. If I keep ExcelFilePath as an empty string, no DFT configuration remains correct. I don't get what is the logical error here.

Comment: The broken components are due to mapping errors arising due to initial set path. Can you please guide me further on what to do?